# Makefile shell function and environment vars

Tags: python, postgresql, makefile, multicorn

I'm playing around with [Multicorn](https://multicorn.org/) for Postgres, and its Makefile doesn't seem to play nice with Python virtual environments. It wants to install itself to the system Python in spite of pyenv. I think this is happening because its Makefile is doing this to find the Python version:

```
$(shell ${PYTHON} --version 2>&1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1-2)
```

From what I've read, shell starts an entirely new shell, and it doesn't seem to carry over the environment variables that pyenv sets to point everything to a certain Python version.

Wondering if anybody has had a similar problem and how they might have gotten around it.

Thanks!

Comment: As you mentioned, some shells do not copy the environment variable to the subshell.  FYR - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/319151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the pyenv version via the PYENV_VERSION environment variable. I'd imagine something like:

```
PYENV_VERSION=your_virtualenv make
```

to work.